# In C++, how to create a global instance of a class (with no parameterless constructor) in the main function?

Tags: c++

I have a variable of a user defined type which I declare outside the main function but which I want to instantiate in the main function

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
    private:
        int x;
    public: 
        MyClass(int x) {
            this->x = x + 1;
        }

        int GetX() {
            return x;
        }
};

MyClass myInstance; // <------ Why not?

void SomeFunction(MyClass a) {
    // do stuff with a
}

int ComplicatedFunction() {
    // do lots of work
    return 5;
}

int main()
{
    int x = ComplicatedFunction();

    myInstance = MyClass(x); <------ make instance here because need to calculate x first

    SomeFunction(myInstance);
}
```

So I have `MyClass myInstance;` declared outside of main. And inside main I attempt `myInstance = MyClass(x);`

The compiler (clang) complains that the global declaration is not allowed because the class does not have a parameterless constructor.

1. I do not want to use pointers.
2. I do not want to add a parameterless constructor.
3. I do not want to instantiate myInstance outside of main.
4. This is for learning.
5. How do I get this code to work?
6. Am I missing some fundamental C++ concept here?

Comment: Tr adding a constructor like MyClass(){};

Comment: Welcome to the world of initialization in C++

Comment: But `MyClass myInstance;` *is* an instantiation. You need to break requirement 1, 2 or 3, there's simply no way around that.

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't recommend it, you technically can achieve this by making your global variable an optional:

```
std::optional<MyClass> myInstance;

int main()
{
    int x = ComplicatedFunction();

    myInstance = MyClass(x);    

    SomeFunction(*myInstance);
}
```

This satisfies all your requirements. I admit, this isn't a pointer but it behaves very much like it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your class has no constructor like `MyClass()`. So you either construct it with `MyClass myInstance(0);` or you add the empty constructor to your class. This means that you cannot do it without either braking at least one of the first three rules that you have imposed. Moreover, in your example, rule 3 is already broken as you are instantiating your class outside of your main function.

```
class MyClass {
    private:
        int x;
    public: 
        MyClass() = default; // <-- This is the constructor that you are missing.
        MyClass(int x) {
            this->x = x + 1;
        }

        int GetX() {
            return x;
        }
};
```

Comment: IMO `MyClass() = default;` would be better.

Comment: Where would `constexpr` go?

Comment: on the constructors

Answer (score 0):

> So I have `MyClass myInstance;` declared outside of `main`.

It is also **defined**

> I do not want to instantiate `myInstance` outside of `main`.

But you do.

You can simply have

```
// Remove global definition
// MyClass myInstance;

int main()
{
    int x = ComplicatedFunction();
    MyClass myInstance(x);

    SomeFunction(myInstance);
}
```